# Grails 3.1.16 - Call method of session scope service from scheduled service

Tags: spring, grails, spring-framework-beans

I created a test basic application on Grails 3.1.16 that has **two services**, a first async and **scheduled** service (ex. FirstService) calling a second **session scoped** service (ex. SessionScopeService), as below:

"**FirstService.groovy**":

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled

class FirstService {

   def sessionScopeService
   boolean lazyInit = false

   @Async
   @Scheduled(cron="*/10 * * * * MON-FRI") 
   void firstServiceMethod() {
       sessionScopeService.serviceMethod()
   }
}
```

"**SessionScopeService.groovy**":

```
class SessionScopeService {

   static scope = "session"
   static proxy = "true"

   def serviceMethod() {
       log.info("test OK")
   }
}
```

The application fails to start, reporting scope session error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup 
failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 

with name 'firstService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionScopeService ': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:778)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:364)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at testservice.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionScopeService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1248)
at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
... 25 common frames omitted
```

I also tried to create manually scoped proxy on '**resources.groovy**' :

```
  beans = {

     sessionScopeServiceProxy(ScopedProxyFactoryBean) {
        targetBeanName = 'sessionScopeService'
        proxyTargetClass = true
    }
  }
```

and then in the FirstService injected this proxy:

```
  def sessionScopeServiceProxy
```

but without success (the method of "sessionScopeServiceProxy" is not even recognized by the "FirstService").

How can I solve this? 
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use a new `SessionScopeService` instance each time your 'job' runs, so you should be using 'prototype' as the scope and manually get the bean in the `firstServiceMethod` execution : `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean(SessionScopeService)`. This way, each time your 'job' kicks in, a new 'SessionScopeService' will be created for that execution.

Comment: I thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I can not use a "prototype" session in "SessionScopeService": the code is a simple example of a more complex project, in which "SessionScopeService" is a service that must have "session" scope, since it's called simultaneously by multiple sessions (and furthermore not just from a single service 'firstService').

Comment: Since your method is called from a scheduled job, you will never have a user session bounded to the thread thus getting the error you pasted in your question. You should move your code in another service that is in another scope.